# I have a wordpress site and i want to delete last two lines from all my posts remember lines are not same any plugin or solution?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site and i have nearly 500 posts want to delete last two lines from all my posts remember lines are not same any plugin or solution?

Comment: You probably want to ask this on the wordpress Stack Exchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP_Query to get all the posts, use the `wp_update_post()` function on each one, and based on what separates the "last two lines" of each post, explode it as a delimiter.

If your post is "Hi. My name is Xhynk. I love WordPress. Usually." And you have another that's "Hi. This is a post. Just a post. Yup. Just a post. Yeah."

You can use a WP_Query to grab the posts, and modify the post content with:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = explode( '. ', $content ); //explode into array joined at every period followed by space
$lines = count( $content ); // 3 in the first, 6 in the second

$count = 0;
foreach( $content as $line ){
    $count++;
    $new_content .= $line.'. ';
    if( $count == $lines - 2) break;
}
```

And then use `wp_update_post()` to swap the content. You just need an identical way to identify the last 2 lines of each post.

If you're not familiar with WP_Query and wp_insert_post, or MySQL queries with the $wpdb object, you may not want to attempt this and just do it manually. Also, take a backup of your database before bulk modifying anything like this.